# .NET 6 Dependency Resolution - register implementation that loads a registration from the same list

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, .net-6.0

I'm trying to understand the underlying issue the causes the DI container to loop when trying to construct a registration that relies on a registration from the same list. For example, let's say I have the following code:

```
public class ImplementationFactory
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IImplementation> _implementations;

    public ImplementationFactory(IEnumerable<IImplementation> implementations)
    {
        _implementations = implementations;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IImplementation> GetAll(List<string> names)
    {
        return _implementations.Where(i => names.Contains(i.Name))
               ?? throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}

public static class ImplementationNames
{
    public const string ImplementationOne = "One";

    public const string ImplementationTwo = "Two";
}

public interface IImplementation
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class ImplementationOne : IImplementation
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public ImplementationOne(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class ImplementationTwo : IImplementation
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public ImplementationTwo(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

When I run the following test, a loop occurs.

```
public class DependencyInjectionTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void CheckSecondImplementationCanLoadFirstImplementationUsingFactory()
    {
        try
        {
            var collection = new ServiceCollection();

            collection.AddTransient<IImplementation, ImplementationOne>(x =>
                new ImplementationOne(ImplementationNames.ImplementationOne));

            collection.AddTransient<ImplementationFactory>();

            collection.AddTransient<IImplementation, ImplementationTwo>(x =>
            {
                // this doesn't seem to be valid and causes a loop
                var loadedImplementation = x.GetRequiredService<ImplementationFactory>()
                    .GetAll(new List<string> {ImplementationNames.ImplementationOne});

                return new ImplementationTwo(ImplementationNames.ImplementationTwo);
            });

            var provider = collection.BuildServiceProvider(validateScopes: true);

            provider.GetRequiredService<ImplementationFactory>()
                .GetAll(new List<string> {ImplementationNames.ImplementationTwo});
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

This is an example of a very complex DI resolution issue I have in an existing repository. I realise there are other ways to resolve this by implementing different interfaces/factories but I would like to understand how the DI container tries to resolve the second implementation and why it fails when trying to resolve the first registration inside the factory delegate.

Thank you!

Comment: Your problem is not the order of the *registration*. It's the fact that your `ImplFactory` constructor needs an injection of `IEnumerable<IImplementation>`. To inject the `IEnumerable`, the provider needs to resolve all implementations. But in its attempt to resolve `ImplTwo`, you have your problematic code that tries to resolve `ImplFactory` - which will call its constructor. That constructor, as we have just discussed, needs to inject `IEnumerable<IImplementation>`, etc, etc. That's your loop right there.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that the endless cycle happening is pretty evident. Minimal reproducer should be something like the following (i.e. no implementations required):

```
var collection = new ServiceCollection();
collection.AddTransient<ImplementationFactory>();
collection.AddTransient<IImplementation>(x =>
{
    // this doesn't seem to be valid and causes a loop
    var loadedImplementation = x.GetRequiredService<ImplementationFactory>()
        .GetAll(new List<string> {});

    return loadedImplementation.First();
});

var provider = collection.BuildServiceProvider(validateScopes: true);

provider.GetRequiredService<ImplementationFactory>();


public interface IImplementation
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class ImplementationFactory
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IImplementation> _implementations;

    public ImplementationFactory(IEnumerable<IImplementation> implementations)
    {
        _implementations = implementations;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IImplementation> GetAll(List<string> names)
    {
        return _implementations.Where(i => names.Contains(i.Name))
               ?? throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

To resolve `ImplementationFactory` ALL the registered `IImplementation` should be resolved, including the one which resolves `ImplementationFactory` i.e. resolve `ImplementationFactory` -> resolve all `IImplementation`'s -> resolve the one which uses `ImplementationFactory` -> resolve `ImplementationFactory` ..., hence the infinite cycle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you able to elaborate on the order of which these registrations need to occur, that last sentence is very confusing.

Comment: @Appa order does not matter in this case, just rework the approach.

Comment: Don't understand this answer sorry. It's just plain confusing. Managed to work it out from explanation that NPras gave.

Comment: @Appa what is confusing exactly? It seems to say exactly the same as NPases one. And reduces the reproducer to a minimal one.

Comment: @Appa as for the order or registration - it has effect only when you register multiple implementations for the same type and then resolve a single one. So your situation can be solved by changing order of registrations.